# Design and development of Android app that can predict estimated time of arrival using GPS

Tags: java, android, algorithm, gps

My project is to design an Android app that will be fitted in school buses so that I can send automated SMS to parents when bus is late.

I need to calculate expected arrival time for the next stop and also create a mySql database schema to store the points.

What will the algorithm to calculate the ETA look like and how should I design my Database Schema?

I stumbled upon this research paper here (http://ntl.bts.gov/lib/17000/17500/17573/PB2001102278.pdf) but it only talks about algorithm.

Also the research paper is very old so it is using technologies that is non-existent now.

How should I proceed for this? Server side is not a problem as it is already been done using [openGTS](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the time you reach a location to the usual time you reach that location. If you are X minutes late, assume you will be about X minutes late to every subsequent location on the route.

Comment: Sounds good but could you please elaborate as to how would I compare coordinates with coordinates and time already stored. Do I need to store every Coordinates sent by device in my database?

Comment: That's completely up to you. You could, for example, send/store coordinates each time the bus is stopped for more than 10 seconds. You could send coordinates every two minutes. The right method depends on precisely what information you need. For example, do you need to predict arrival times at particular stops? Do you need to alert individual parents? Or do you just need a general "Bus X is Y minutes late right now"? (Hint: Ask detailed questions if you want detailed answers.)